# Dropdown boxes for WPF settings?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am completely new to WPF and I tried to google this, so I'll ask here. I am making a program that uses a DataGrid and I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

I selected this attribute `DataGrid->Columns->Collection->DataGridTextColumn->Layout->Width`.
Under Width, the default is Auto. I am used to having a dropdown box for the options. I see that I have choices marked by this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridlength.aspx) describing the DataGridLength structure. Is there anyway I can have the dropdown boxes instead? Or some other alternative that is fast and quick besides googling the answer?

Comment: Changing values from the properties panel will only get you so far. I suggest you get used to using the XAML editor.